# React Router issue trying to inject auth service to auth component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The following code works but doesn't allow me to pass auth object through route to the authService.

```
    const routes = {

      path: '/',
      indexRoute: { onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/home') } ,
      childRoutes: [
        {
        onEnter: requireAuth,
        childRoutes: [
          require('./routes/home').default,
        ]
        },
          require('./routes/auth').default, 
      ]
    };


    ReactDOM.render((
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router
          history={history}
          routes={routes}
        />
      </Provider>
    ), document.getElementById('smartadmin-root'));
```

However the standard method below doesn't show my login form.

```
  ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
   <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <indexRoute onEnter={(nextState, replace) => replace('/home')} />
        <Route component={Home} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
        </Route>
          <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('smartadmin-root'));
```

What am I missing?